# How do I improve a question that's been put on hold?

Tags: support, closed-questions

My question has been put on hold as unclear:

[How do I generate page numbers when using the html2latex library?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115625/how-do-i-generate-page-numbers-when-using-the-html2latex-library)

Since I can't edit or comment on it, how do I help clarify the question?

Comment: This happens to questions that are migrated and then closed on the target site. Flagging would be the only option.

Answer (score 3):

I'm working through older unanswered questions trying to deal with them if I can.  The fact that things got locked here is unfortunate: I've (hopefully) unlocked it now!

Comment: Which `tag` would be synonymous to `on hold` ? Is `too-localized` ok?

Comment: @texenthusiast I think [meta-tag:closed-questions].